# Enlarge image onclick android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Hi I am trying to develop an android application,but I am stuck,please help me
I am trying to enlarge an image on click so that the user on clicking the image can see full image.I have managed to write some code but its not working

my java class is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class quiz extends Activity {

    boolean imageTouch = false;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;


    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;

    int mode = NONE;

    public GestureDetector mDetector;

    @
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz);

        ImageView imgp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        imgp.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @
            Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                System.out.println("matrix=" + savedMatrix.toString());
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;


                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                        oldDist = spacing(event);

                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(mid, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        v.performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;

                        break;


                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                event.getY() - start.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                }
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);


                return true;
            }
            private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            }

            private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean "its not working"?

Comment: iam not getting the image enlarged on clicking it ,but no error has been shown while running the app @kostek